# Vertical Scrolling gets disabled when mouse is outside of dropdown menu (run my snippet to understand)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, I have a button which opens my dropdown menu. When it is open, an invisible "page blocker" element also gets enabled so I can detect when the user clicks outside of the dropdown in order to close the dropdown menu again. However, as you can try for yourself, you you attempt to scroll down on the page when the dropdown menu is opened, some strangeness happens. If you scroll ontop of the menu, scrolling works. But if you scroll outside of it, scrolling gets disabled which is NOT what I want D:

(EDIT) PS: the height: 100%; everywhere is desireable because of 100vh does not work on mobile which this website will be mostly intended for

```js
const btn_dropdown = document.getElementById("btn_dropdown");
const content_dropdown = document.getElementById("content_dropdown");
const page_blocker = document.getElementById("page_blocker");

btn_dropdown.addEventListener("click", () => {
  page_blocker.classList.add("open");
  content_dropdown.classList.add("open");
});

page_blocker.addEventListener("click", () => {
  page_blocker.classList.remove("open");
  content_dropdown.classList.remove("open");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.body_overflow_fix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#btn_dropdown {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: skyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content_dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: orange;
}
#content_dropdown.open {
  display: block;
}
#page_blocker {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#page_blocker.open {
  display: block;
}
main {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body_overflow_fix">

  <header>
    <div id="btn_dropdown">TOGGLE</div>
    <div id="content_dropdown"></div>
    <div id="page_blocker"></div>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    
  </main>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are using `position: fixed;`.

```
#page-blocker{
  position:fixed;
{
```

if you remove `position: fixed` it works.